# Cannot create Nexus 5X emulator using cli

Tags: android, command-line-interface, android-virtual-device

Nexus 5X device is available on the Android Studio GUI of the android device manager, but the command line tool "android list devices" does not show the device profile for Nexus 5X. 
I know I can create it manually and it is not hard, but if anyone knows what the issue is, it'll be helpful in automating the process.

Thank you.

Comment: Can you provide the commands that you're using & the errors you're seeing?

Comment: `android list devices` as mentioned produces a list of device configs which does not include Nexus 5X, however does include Nexus 5. There are no errors just missing device configs.